# Non blocking python process or thread

Tags: python

I have a simple app that listens to a socket connection.  Whenever certain chunks of data come in a callback handler is called with that data.  In that callback I want to send my data to another process or thread as it could take a long time to deal with. I was originally running the code in the callback function, but it blocks!!

What's the proper way to spin off a new task?

Comment: Are you using any framework? If so, said framework could also provide a way to spin off a deferred task.

Comment: No framework, strait up python madness.

Comment: Then the `threading` module is your friend! Spin off your own deferred-task mechanism. Or use a framework if you're lazy. =)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) is the threading library usually used for resource-based multithreading. The [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) library is another library, but designed more for running intensive parallel computing tasks; threading is generally the recommended library in your case.

Example

```
import threading, time
def my_threaded_func(arg, arg2):
    print "Running thread! Args:", (arg, arg2)
    time.sleep(10)
    print "Done!"

thread = threading.Thread(target=my_threaded_func, args=("I'ma", "thread"))
thread.start()
print "Spun off thread"
```

Answer (score 6):

The multiprocessing module has [worker pools](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). If you don't need a pool of workers, you can use [Process](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) to run something in parallel with your main program.

Answer (score 3):

```
    import threading
    from   time import sleep
    import sys

    # assume function defs ...

    class myThread (threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, threadID):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.threadID = threadID
        def run(self):
            if self.threadID == "run_exe":
                run_exe()

    def main():
        itemList = getItems()

        for item in itemList:
            thread = myThread("run_exe")
            thread.start()
            sleep(.1)
            listenToSocket(item)
            while (thread.isAlive()):
                pass # a way to wait for thread to finish before looping
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```

The sleep between thread.start() and listenToSocket(item) ensures that the thread is established before you begin to listen. I implemented this code in a unit test framework were I had to launch multiple non-blacking processes (len(itemList) number of times) because my other testing framework (listenToSocket(item)) was dependent on the processes.

un_exe() can trigger a subprocess call that can be blocking (i.e. invoking pipe.communicate()) so that output data from the execution will still be printed in time with the python script output. But the nature of threading makes this ok.

So this code solves two problems - print data of a subprocess without blocking script execution AND dynamically create and start multiple threads sequentially (makes maintenance of the script better if I ever add more items to my itemList later).

Comment: I also relize now you could invoke different commands based on the threadID you create the thread with. This could be useful if specific items require a unique modification of execution. TYPO: 'un_exe()' should be 'run_exe()'.